# "Can't Move Doc" Error Upon Opening RStudio or Restarting R Session

Tags: r, rstudio

Nearly even time I open RStudio or restart the R session, I see the error shown in the picture below. It's essentially these two "Can't move doc" error messages but there are actually multiple that I have to individually click "ok" on or press enter. Presumably one appears for each of the new "Untitled1.R" code scripts that also pop up when I open the application or restart R.

It used to be only slightly annoying to mash the Return key multiple times until all the errors disappeared and then closed all the windows, but the number of new windows and error boxes seems to multiply. Just today, the same thing happened and literally hundreds of new windows and error messages appeared. It took me well over 5 minutes just to get past the error messages (I'm not being hyperbolic), so needless to say the problem is extremely annoying.

Could anyone help me on this? Has anyone encountered this or know why it would be happening? Any help would be deeply appreciated.

[image]

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing RStudio and R multiple times to no avail, though I'd be open to trying it again.

Comment: Looks like you cross-posted to another site as well: https://community.rstudio.com/t/cant-move-doc-error-upon-opening-rstudio-or-restarting-r-session/182499